# Cakephp send html content to a blank view

Tags: cakephp

I am using Cakephp 2 and i do generate html content into an action 
I need to send the html content to a blank view.

I have the controller action send :

```
public function send()  {
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
           $this->request->data['Doc']['value'] = 0.01;        
           $this->request->data['Doc']['name'] = 'OneName';
        }        
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {              
            echo $this->generate($this->request->data);              
        }       
    }
```

And the action generate :

```
public function generate($data)   {    
    $html= new htmlGenerator($data);
    return $html->getOutput();
}
```

I have the views `send.ctp` and `generate.ctp`

When i do send the form the html generated stays at the top of the current view

How can i send to generate.ctp view passing this->request->data to generate action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be something like this

```
public function send()  {       
    $this->autoRender = false;      

    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
       $this->request->data['Doc']['value'] = 0.01;        
       $this->request->data['Doc']['name'] = 'OneName';
       $this->render('path/to/your/send');
    }        

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->set('generated',$this->generate($this->request->data));
        $this->render('path/to/your/generate');
    }       
}
```

and then in your `generate.ctp`

```
<?php echo $generated ?>
```